# Why my "VS Code" is showing single color in my code editing area?

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

[image: my vs code screenshot]

I have tried deleting my vs code and reinstalling. Still facing the same issue and can't find the solution on the internet

Comment: look at your minimap, there is a lot that has color, use the TextMate Scope inspector to see the scope of the green part

Comment: You might have an unclosed template literal string (\`) so it thinks you're inside a string. That wouldn't explain the different colored question marks/parentheses though

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Select `JavaScript React` or `JavaScript` in Language Mode from Bottom Right Corner instead of `Javascript (Babel)`.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work its showing the same thing with javascript react and btw cannot find javascript there is javascript babel and javascript react...

Comment: Can you share this specific file? And does this happen in this file only or in every file?

Comment: It's happening in most of my files

Comment: It's possible that this may be caused by your theme Try Changing the theme too. Try Dark or Dark+

Comment: I have tried that too